# Can this Set be empty when I validate it with the Validator class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, hibernate-validator

I don't really understand how the function isEmpty() can return true when it's validated with a valid DTO object.
In the anomalies variable, after I checked with the debugger, we have the following values

```
interpolatedMessage: "Veuillez renseigner si votre véhicule est dérogatoire ou non." (id=344)
messageTemplate: {vehicule.derogatoire.obligatoire}" (id=348)
```

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: true but was: false

In this case, the test might be written in a wrong way?

```
 @Test
    public void testValidator() {

        VehiculeFrontDto vehiculeFrontDto = new VehiculeFrontDto();
        vehiculeFrontDto.setImmat("test");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setMarque("test2");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setModele("test3");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setDatePremiereImmat(new Date());
        vehiculeFrontDto.setSituation(SituationVehiculeEnum.CAPA.getCode());

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        
        Set<ConstraintViolation<VehiculeFrontDto>> anomalies = validator.validate(vehiculeFrontDto, Default.class);
        Assertions.assertTrue(anomalies.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Can you please provide the content of VehiculeFrontDto.java as well?

Comment: If the DTO is valid, an empty set is the only thing I'd expect - there are no violations. If the test is failing, the DTO is not valid. The violation(s) contain not just the (interpolated) message, but also the constraint annotation that triggered the violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you validate the DTO with the validator, *all* validation annotations are checked. Did you maybe forget to set the `derogatoire` property? Because your message template says `{vehicule.derogatoire.obligatoire}`. If your DTO was valid, the returned list should indeed be empty, but it is not! You probably need to append your code like this:

```java
        VehiculeFrontDto vehiculeFrontDto = new VehiculeFrontDto();
        vehiculeFrontDto.setImmat("test");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setMarque("test2");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setModele("test3");
        vehiculeFrontDto.setDatePremiereImmat(new Date());
        vehiculeFrontDto.setSituation(SituationVehiculeEnum.CAPA.getCode());
        // added line
        vehiculeFrontDto.setDerogatoire(true); // or false?
```